# Create entity property that selects one object from a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a parent to child relationship where I have one parent record and six child records, differentiated by a type key. These child records are required so I would like to, rather than create a list property for all six children,

```
public virtual IList<ChildRecord> Children { get; set; }
```

I would rather create six properties and get / set them individually.

```
public virtual ChildRecord Child1 { get; set; }
public virtual ChildRecord Child2 { get; set; }
public virtual ChildRecord Child3 { get; set; }
public virtual ChildRecord Child4 { get; set; }
public virtual ChildRecord Child5 { get; set; }
public virtual ChildRecord Child6 { get; set; }
```

Is this a possibility? I'm playing around with my Fluent mapping without much luck.

Comment: Just a thought. This would generate 1 query per child, in stead of 1 for all. I would get them all and split up in code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176214/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-with-where-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you map the collection to a private field, and you create your six properties that access that collection through get & set based on your conditions?